# URL Transformer

Tags: java, string

I want to make a class in Java called `URLTransformer`.

Let's say I have a blog entry and want to format my text (e.g. because some words are in Swedish).

This is my code right now:

```
public class URLTransformer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String basurl = "http://www.mybloggsys.com/user_abc/";
        String[] rubriker = {
            "Nu Kommer Vintern till aland",
            "Onskningar ar nagot man vill uppna",
            "Just English Letters"
        };

        for (String rubrik : rubriker) {
            String rubrik2=rubrik.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_").replace("Å", "a").replace("å", "a").replace("ä", "a").replace("Ö", "o");
            URLTransformer transformer = new URLTransformer();
            URLTransformer(basurl, rubrik2);
            String url = transformer.getURL();
            String aElement = transformer.getAElement();
            System.out.println(rubrik2);
            System.out.println(url);
            System.out.println(aElement);
        }
        URLTransformer transformer = new URLTransformer();
    }

    private String getAElement() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    private String getURL() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    private static void URLTransformer(String basurl, String rubrik2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Now, I can get Eclipse to execute this code but I get a lot of "Null" messages. Is it possible to not get it or does it even matter after compiling my code? In my homework task, the final code should look exactly like this:

```
Nu kommer Vinter till Åland
http://www.mybloggsys.com/user_abc/nu_kommer_vintern_till_aland
<a href="(url link same as above)/nu_kommer_vintern_till_aland">Nu Kommer Vintern till        Åland</a>
Önskningar är något man vill uppnå
(url link)/onskningar_ar_nagot_man_vill_uppna
<a href="(url link)/onskningar_ar_nagot_man_vill_uppna">Önskningar är något    man vill uppnå</a>
Just English Letters
(url link)/just_english_letters
<a href="(url link)/just_english_letters">Just English Letters</a>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, it feels like it almost works just this `</a>` element thing and null messages that are left.

Comment: What are those 'Null' messages?

Comment: Show us the input you use and the output you get.

Comment: How could you expect a result different from null as you only retun null in the methods getAElement() and getURL() ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for you:

```
    public class URLTransformer {

        private String baseurl;
        private String baseString;

        // Constructor of the class that uses a base url and a base string 
        public URLTransformer(String baseurl, String baseString) {
            super();
            this.baseurl = baseurl;
            this.baseString = baseString;
        }

        // Method that return the href calculated 
        private String getHref() {
            // transform the string to remove non english characters with _ instead of spaces
            return baseurl + baseString.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_").replace("Å", "a").replace("å", "a").replace("ä", "a").replace("Ö", "o");
        }

        // return a <a> link with a call to the href link method
        private String getAElement() {
            StringBuilder aElement = new StringBuilder();
            aElement.append("<a href=\"");
            aElement.append(getHref());
            aElement.append("\">");
            aElement.append(baseString);
            aElement.append("</a>");
            return aElement.toString();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String basurl = "http://www.mybloggsys.com/user_abc/";
            String[] rubriker = { "Nu Kommer Vintern till aland", "Onskningar ar nagot man vill uppna", "Just English Letters" };

            // iterate over the 
            for (String rubrik : rubriker) {
                URLTransformer transformer = new URLTransformer(basurl, rubrik); // creation of the class object that is able to make a link from the string
                System.out.println(rubrik); // prints the provided string
                System.out.println(transformer.getHref()); // use of the getHref method to get an url from the string
                System.out.println(transformer.getAElement()); // display of the <a> element 
            }
        }

    }
```

Note : I've added comments to the code and see my comment below to have explanations on what was wrong with the provided code.

Comment: Could yout please explain what you have changed and why?

Comment: I've changed many things : first i've added a constructor that use the parameters you provide in order to stock them for later use second i've added 2 methods that return the href of your link and the complete <a> element. There were methods but they were not implemented at all and also the use of variables in the main method were a misunderstanding of the whole use of the class that should do a transform

Comment: Then please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28232415/edit) and explain them.

Comment: @BoutDePain    Thank you a lot ! :) That code was beautiful and it works well now, perfectly done, thank you again so much, really appreciate your effort.